How to test if a DOM element has changed in Cypress?
I am trying Cypress (with TypeScript) to see if it might be suitable for E2E testing a specific web app. One of the challenges I have is that I do not have a seeder to trivially recreate the database; it would be ideal to fully remote control the app from the tests, so that the database is fresh for every test. That is a team decision, and thus (for now) the strategy will be to test against a staging environment where the database is a recent copy of production.
This means that where I take an action in a test, it shall be regarded as a sufficient test for something in the DOM to have changed. For example, I am wanting to test a filtering screen, and when a filter is applied, the results must be different to what they were before. However, this is proving rather tricksy.
Here is the code to apply the filter:
visitCountryPage();
cy
    .get('#sharedTrips .filtersContainer button')
    .then((buttons: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => {
        buttons[0].click();
    })
    // Now click on a menu option
    .get('#sharedTrips .filtersContainer label[for="experiencesrelax"]')
    .click();

Here is what happens:

The first get() finds the button to open the menu
Then we use then() to get the 0th element to click the filter option
The second get() finds a menu option
The final click selects the filter

To give readers an idea of my thought process, here is what I have tried:
let initialIdeas: Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> = getTripIdeas();
cy
    .get('#sharedTrips .filtersContainer button')
    .then((buttons: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => {
        buttons[0].click();
    })
    // Now click on a menu option
    .get('#sharedTrips .filtersContainer label[for="experiencesrelax"]')
    .click()
    .then(() => {
        getTripIdeas().should('not.equal', initialIdeas);
    });

You can see that getTripIdeas() is an external function that returns a Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> via a DOM read. I appreciate that at the top of the code this is likely to be some kind of Promise that is not yet resolved, but I was hoping that in the final then(), the not.equal test would resolve both the new and old versions in order to do a meaningful comparison.
However, this passes green even if I take out the final click(), which should not happen.
I am wondering now whether the object references to these resolved Promises are always going to be different (which is why the test always passes), and thus I should convert them to the text contents of the elements within, so they are comparable. Or am I wrong in assuming that the last should() is going to resolve the two Promises, and if so, how can I do that succinctly?

You have a number of anti-patterns, but since it's not the code review site I'll just focus on the the main idea.
What you're trying to do is use Chai assertions (the .should() command is an implementation of expect()) to compare Chainable result objects. Unfortunately there is no Chai method that does that.
Therefore you need to unpack the Chainable with .then((valueInsideChainable) =>. To preserve the initialValues Cypress says you should use an alias instead of a Javascript variable.
Further, it should be a static type alias. See api/commands/as#Arguments.
cy.wrap(getTripIdeas()).as('initialValues', {type:'static'});  

// actions to change the DOM
cy.get('#sharedTrips .filtersContainer button')
  .first()
  .click();                     // prefer Cypress click to jQuery click

// don't chain after click()
cy.get('#sharedTrips .filtersContainer label[for="experiencesrelax"]')
  .click()

/*
  Using {type:'query'} for the final values since we need 
  .should('not.deep.eq'...) to re-query until passing
*/
cy.wrap(getTripIdeas()).as('finalValues', {type:'query'}); 

// compare the variables
cy.get('@initialValues').then(initial => {
  cy.get('@finalValues')
    .invoke('toArray')       // change JQuery<HTMLElement> to HTMLElement[]
    .should('not.deep.eq', initial.toArray())
})

getTripIdeas() would actually be better as a custom command, since you deal with the Chainable result. It could then be chained directly (would not need wrap()).
The not.deep.eq comparison is a bit naive since we are dealing with JQuery<HTMLElement>, if this is a React app the elements are likely to be re-rendered with new copies after the click actions.
It would be better to compare some aspect of the elements, such as the innerText, or value for HTMLInputElement.

Wowsers, this is excellent, thank you. It is going to take me a while to wrap my head around this! Despite much research on Stack and elsewhere, this is the first time I am seeing as().

Now that you've laid out how to use getTripIdeas() in separate wraps, it looks like that function could just create an array of trip idea headings, which would be much more comparable. I originally had it that way, but I went down a (wrong) rabbithole in which everything had to be in a single chain, and thus getTripIdeas() became chainable.

I will test this out tomorrow

The core concepts are here Variables and Aliases but like a lot of Cypress concepts they have "morphed" a bit - the as() command was changed recently to re-query when value is extracted, but that defeats this use-case since initialValues would be re-read from DOM after the click action - hence static option.

You can of course just cy.wrap(getTripIdeas()).then(initial => {... (instead of using .as().

I've made a couple of edits based on what the runtime or IDE was telling me!

So, it looks like wrap() was not necessary. With this used to invoke getTripIdeas(), I get this error: "Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise". Since getTripIdeas returns a Cypress.Chainable, I can just do getTripIdeas().as('initialValues', { type: 'static' }).

Now, interestingly, after the click that applies a filter, the not-deep-equal test failed because the new trip ideas had not yet loaded. So to get this to pass, I have added a cy.wait(3000), which does not feel very idiomatic for Cypress, which (per the docs) seems to encourage "wait until" for DOM changes.

Is there a simple way to achieve this without the fixed-length wait? In a synchronous system (e.g. Selenium and PHP) I would just write a wait/loop function that tests the DOM using a custom closure, and then sleep for 0.5s on failure before retrying, or return success, with a loop timeout of 10s for permanent failure cases.

I have accepted your excellent answer, but I will ask a new specific question about extending it to give Cypress the responsibility of the wait-test loop. I think this may be of interest to the wider community. I will add a link here once I have written it, and your input would be much welcomed!

A link to my new question.
